# Retornar intervalo de strings Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, query, oracle, pl-sql

Bom dia !
Preciso retornar o valor dentro de uma string que fica entre um intervalo de `|` no select abaixo eu consigo pegar o valor a partir do primeiro `|`.
O resultado esperado é: `83,1`

```
SELECT SUBSTR('1410,00|83,1|39,29|1410m|', 
       INSTR('1410,00|83,1|39,29|1410m|', '|') + 1, 
       LENGTH('1410,00|83,1|39,29|1410m|')) TTR
  FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar uma *regular expression* combinada com a função [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm):

```
select regexp_substr('1410,00|83,1|39,29|1410m|','[^\|]+',1,2) from dual
```

A função irá aplicar a *regular expression* `[^\|]+` que irá buscar por um pipe (o "+" no final significa "uma ou mais ocorrências"), a partir da posição 1, retornando a segunda ocorrência.
Veja que como você quer o segundo valor "83,2", o parâmetro final da função foi "2", no caso "3" irá retornar "39,29" e assim por diante.

Aqui o fiddle funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a6382/10

Comment: Ricardo Monstroo :) ! Obrigado man ! Eu tinha conseguido fazer com vários SUBSTR e INSTR, mas a sua solução ficou muito melhor, obrigado mais uma vez !